# Using histogram equalization in color image in js

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, histogram, rgb

I want to use OpenCV histogram equalization with color image output but I didn't find a way to do this.
here is the tutorial:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d74/tutorial_js_histogram_equalization.html

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
cv.equalizeHist(src, dst);
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', src);
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
src.delete(); dst.delete();
```

this code converts image to gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you *can* use histogram equalization with color images:

- cvtConvert() to hsv (not grayscale)
- split() the hsv image into seperate h,s,v planes
- apply equalizeHist() on the V (grayscale intensity) channel
- merge() hsv planes back
- cvtConvert() back to RGBA

Comment: Another possibility is to use histogram equalization on each of the BGR channels, which should give a similar result as color normalization in GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I found with @berak help.
this will equalize histogram for color images

```
    let imgElement = document.getElementById("ImgViewImage"); // img element with ImgViewImage id
    let src = cv.imread(imgElement);
    let dst = new cv.Mat();
    let hsvPlanes = new cv.MatVector();
    let mergedPlanes = new cv.MatVector();
    cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 0);
    cv.split(src, hsvPlanes);
    let H = hsvPlanes.get(0);
    let S = hsvPlanes.get(1);
    let V = hsvPlanes.get(2);
    cv.equalizeHist(V, V);
    mergedPlanes.push_back(H);
    mergedPlanes.push_back(S);
    mergedPlanes.push_back(V);
    cv.merge(mergedPlanes, src);
    cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_HSV2RGB, 0);
    cv.imshow("canvasOutput", dst); // canavas element with canvasOutput id
    src.delete();
    dst.delete();
    hsvPlanes.delete();
    mergedPlanes.delete();
```